# C# WPF Combobox selection event based on Combobox list populated from text file

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a Combobox drop down that is populated from a text file. The combobox is populated with multiple server groups. This is working fine.

```
servergroups.txt
Group1
Group2
Group3
```

```
       public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ComboBox2.ItemsSource = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\temp\servergroups.txt");
        }
```

The problem i have is that i am also trying to populate a listbox of servers from a server text file based on what server group selected in the combobox.

```
group1.txt
server1
server2
server3
```

```
        private void ComboBox2_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (((ComboBoxItem)ComboBox2.SelectedItem).Content.Equals("Group1"))
            {
                Listbox1.ItemsSource = null;
                Listbox1.Items.Clear();
                Listbox1.ItemsSource = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\temp\Group1.txt");
                Listbox1.ScrollIntoView(Listbox1.Items[0]);
            }
```

I am getting the following exception when i select any item from the combobox dropdown

***System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem'.'***

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message clearly says that `SelectedItem` is of type `string`.

When you assign a collection of strings to the `ItemsSource` property of a [Selector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector?view=windowsdesktop-7.0), the `SelectedItem` is also a string:

```
if ((string)ComboBox2.SelectedItem == "Group1")
{
    Listbox1.ItemsSource = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\temp\Group1.txt");
}
```

---

In general, the object held by the `SelectedItem` property is the currently selected element in the `Items` collection, so that the following condition is true when `SelectedIndex` >= 0:

```
selector.SelectedItem == selector.Items[selector.SelectedIndex]
```